# How to load different styles on different pages in Umbraco

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, umbraco, umbraco7

I have Master Template where i am Loading all the styles here

```
@{
    Layout = null;
}

<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/socialiconstyle.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/bootstap/css/bootstrap3.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/carousel.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/umasterclass.css" /> 

        <script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    </head>
```

Where as child page is:

```
@{
    Layout = "Master1.cshtml";
}

<div class="internal-wrapper">
   <p>@Umbraco.Field("headingSubline")</p>
    @RenderBody()

</div>
```

Due to the master page include all the style sheets is loading here.

For example I don't want the carousel.css to load in this child page because there is no carousel in this child page so  how to achieve not load all the styles and add some conditions based on the page to load the style any idea or suggestions ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One why is to not include all the css file to the layout page, for instance, carousel.css is using by one or two view pages, then load that css file only that page instead globally.

Layout page:

```
<head>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/socialiconstyle.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/bootstap/css/bootstrap3.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/umasterclass.css" /> 

    @RenderSection("css", false)

    <script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/bootstrap.min.js"</script>

</head>
```

View pages are using that css:

```
@section css {
    <link href="@Url.Content("~/css/carousel.css")" rel="stylesheet"/>
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: hi @Div i have tried such a way in my mater.cs html but the css not even loading on master

Comment: i have to include that in the master page where as my child page i dont want to include

Comment: yeah master page need the carousel where as child dont want

Comment: but this is the temporary solution ryt , incase if another page i dont want to include the umasterclass.css then i have to create again one more master page , so which will duplicate , is there any other way to configure the css based on the page Level and display only certain CSS on certain pages ?

Comment: hi @DIv the main landin gpage have the carousel so i ahve added the carousel,css file in master.cshtml where as some other pages dont have the carousel the internal pages due to it includes the master Layout it calls that CSS also in other pages :(

Comment: hi @DIV thank you i have solved it by using your code :)

Comment: hi @DIV yeas i did :)

Comment: hi @Div  is there any way that we can maintain a configuration files for each pages a set of css files and we can load the files from there , because the current implementation still loads the carousel.css file to other pages because the inner child layout uses the homepage file as parrent

Comment: Hi @GayathriMohan, I will take a look and let you know.

Comment: hi @Div https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48070897/iapplication-could-not-be-found-in-umbraco do u have any idea

Comment: Hi @Gayathri, no I don't have any idea yet, will try once I get some free time :) thanks for letting me know about your issue!

Comment: @GayathriMohan: I'm new to umbraco, downloaded it from [here](https://github.com/umbraco/Umbraco-CMS/releases/tag/release-7.0.0), opened it with VS, build gives me a bunch of error. http://imgr.es/40U7

Comment: i think u have to install all the missing dll files

Comment: @GayathriMohan: Not sure, that dlls generating after build the project :) and also getting more number of errors `The call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties: 'SqlHelper<P>.ExecuteReader(string, params P[])' and 'SqlHelper<P>.ExecuteReader(string, params IParameter[])'`

Answer (score 0):

Another way of solving this is (apart of the accepted answer) is using [ClientDependency](https://github.com/Shazwazza/ClientDependency) which is part of Umbraco already. The benefit of using this package is that it minimises and bundles your assets.

The way of including your css and javascript is like this:

```
@{Html.RequiresCss("~/Css/ColorScheme.css");}
@{
 Html.RequiresJs("~/Js/jquery.js")
     .RequiresJs("~/Js/jquery.validation.js")
     .RequiresJs("~/Js/myCoffeeLib.coffee");
 }
```

To include them into your page then you use:

```
@Html.RenderJsHere()
@Html.RenderCssHere()
```

Going back to the question. You can add additional files from your partial views just adding `@{Html.RequiresCss("~/Css/carousel.css");}`

This will be render where you had your `RenderCssHere` method on your layout.

Comment: hi @Mario Lopez is there any way that we can maintain a configuration files for each pages a set of css files and we can load the files from there , because the current implementation still loads the carousel.css file to other pages because the inner child layout uses the homepage file as parrent

Comment: Check my answer, you can put `{Html.RequiresCss("~/Css/carousel.css");}` in your partial view and it will only be included when you render that partial view.
You can include a bunch of files in a folder: `@{Html.RequiresCssFolder("~/Css/Widgets/");}`