# CS0246: The type or namespace 'IApplication' could not be found

Tags: asp.net, umbraco, umbraco7

While customizing the Dashboard, I tried to add a new Ribbon like media and settings. I have followed the [documentation](http://sam-mullins.com/articles/custom-dashboard-tab-not-appearing-in-custom-section-of-umbraco/)...

```
[Application("siteExporter", "Site Exporter", "tray-icon.png", 10)]
public class SiteExporterApplication : IApplication 
{    
    public SiteExporterApplication () {} 
}
```

... but I have received the following compilation error:

> CS0246: The type or namespace 'IApplication' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

[image: image of error]

What is wrong with the code that is causing this error?

Comment: @Div do you have any idea

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are properly importing the `umbraco.interfaces` namespace in your file. Not doing so may cause the error you're seeing.